# Two points are randomly selected on a line of length $1$

Tags: probability

Two points are randomly selected on a line of length $1$. What is the probability that one of the segments is greater than $\frac{1}{2}$? Points can be placed anywhere between [0, 1], for example. Thanks!

Comment: Notice that a line segment will only be greater than 1/2 if both chosen points are either both to the left or to the right of the middle point. So knowing this I guess you could work out the details

Comment: @TomUltramelonman  What if the first point is at $.1$ and the second at $.9$?  Then the segment between them has length $.8$.

Comment: Oh damn, how could I overlook this ^^ Yea sorry

Comment: @TomUltramelonman That's not correct. Two points divide a segment into three parts and *any* of them may be longer than $\frac 12$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok suppose you take some point $x\in[0,1/2]$. Now taking a second point $y\in[0,1]$, there are two situations where you obtain a segment of length at least $1/2$. Firstly if $y\le 1/2$. Secondly if $y\ge x+1/2$. So for taking a first point $x$, the chance that you have a segment of desired length is $1/2+(1-1/2-x)=1 - x$. Now integrating this over $[0,1/2]$ you get $3/8$. Yu can do the same for $x\in[1/2,1]$. So this gives you a chance of $6/8$.

Comment: Thanks to lulu and CiaPan for the comments.

Comment: This is solid (+1).  My variant, below, does the same thing geometrically...without referring to an integral.  But the underlying principle is the same.

Answer (score 8):

Probability is $3/4$ if points $x$ and $y$ are chosen with uniform probability. That corresponds to the area in color in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

With probability $\frac 12$ both points are on the same side of the midpoint, so we are guaranteed success.

If the points are on opposite sides of the midpoint(a probability $\frac 12$ event, with $P<\frac 12< Q$ say, then again with probability $\frac 12$ we have $Q$ is nearer $1$ than $P$ is near $\frac 12$,so the segment between them has length greater than $\frac 12$.

Thus the total probability Is $$\frac 12+\frac 12\times \frac 12=\frac 34$$

Note:  this is equivalent to asking how probable it is that the three segments formed by the two points can form a triangle (the above shows that the answer is $\frac 14$).  Many proofs for that can be found e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2014/if-you-break-a-stick-at-two-points-chosen-uniformly-the-probability-the-three-r)